# Compare file changes after moving file to new repository and making changes

Tags: git

I have moved files between repositories and made changes to these files. I'd like to diff the changes I've made but the files have been deleted from the source repository and the history isn't in the new repository.

I tried:

`git diff HEAD -- MovedFile.cs C:\OtherRepo\MovedFile.cs`

but I got an error about the file being outside the repository.

Is there a way to do this using git diff?
Or perhaps the history can be moved when a file is moved between repositories?

Using Windows 10 in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git diff` to compare files on disk even outside a repository, just use a syntax that indicates "compare files", not "compare commits" :

```
# drop the 'HEAD --' part :
git diff MovedFile.cs C:\OtherRepo\MovedFile.cs
```

Any diff viewer would work, so :

```
meld MovedFile.cs C:\OtherRepo\MovedFile.cs
winmerge MovedFile.cs C:\OtherRepo\MovedFile.cs
...
# you name it
```

If you have local modifications on `MovedFile.cs`, just stash them before running `git diff`.

---

You can get the complete content of a file stored in a commit using :

```
git show commit:path/to/file
# for example, with HEAD :
git show HEAD:path/to/file
```

You can store it on disk and then use it :

```
git show HEAD:path/to/file > file.tmp
git diff file.tmp somewhere/else/somefile
```

Or use the `<(...)` construct in bash (haven't tested it on windows though) :

```
git diff <(git show HEAD:path/to/file) somewhere/else/somefile
```

Comment: That's what I did after I'd posted the question. What I was hoping for was a way to compare a file directly from the repository against a file outside the file structure of the repository. This would be handy in other scenarios where a git stash wouldn't help.